# Pandas custom response to Rest API

Tags: json, pandas

I am trying to send data from pandas as JSON response to Rest API Post method.

Using standard pandas to json table response `json_table = dataFrame.to_json(orient ='table')` i get below output:

```
{“schema”:
 {“fields”:
   [{“name”:”index”, “type”:”integer”}, 
    {“name”:”col1″, “type”:”string”}, 
    {“name”:”col2″, “type”:”string”}], 
    “primaryKey”:[“index”],  
    “pandas_version”:”1.4.0″},  
    “data”:[{“index”:0, “col1″:”1”, “col2″:”2”}, {“index”:1, “col1″:”3”, “col2″:”4”}]}
```

However, the Rest API is expecting response as below:

```
{
   "structure": {
      "Col1": "col1",
      "Col2": "col2"
   },
   "data": [
      {
         "col1": "1",
         "col2": "2"
      },
      {
         "col1": "3",
         "col2": "4"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can get this desired format? I don't want to hard code the structure and rather it needs to form the structure as per the dataframe.

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `dataframe.to_dict('tight')` for reproducibility?

Comment: Assuming `col1`/`col2` the column names, what are `Col1`/`Col2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming such an input:

```
  col1 col2
0    1    2
1    3    4
```

You can use a custom dictionary and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
import json

out = json.dumps({'structure': {f'Col{i}': c for i,c in
                                enumerate(dataFrame, start=1)},
                  'data': dataFrame.to_dict(orient='records')}, indent=4)
```

*NB. assuming `Col1`/`Col2` to be incremented identifiers, if you have a list you can use `dict(zip(list_of_ids, dataFrame))` as value for `structure`.*

Output:

```
{
    "structure": {
        "Col1": "col1",
        "Col2": "col2"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "col1": "1",
            "col2": "2"
        },
        {
            "col1": "3",
            "col2": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

##### generalization

If you have fixed structure identifiers you can use `zip`:

```
cols = ['Id', 'Address']

out = json.dumps({'structure': dict(zip(cols, dataFrame)),
                  'data': dataFrame.to_dict(orient='records')}, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{
    "structure": {
        "Id": "col1",
        "Address": "col2"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "col1": "1",
            "col2": "2"
        },
        {
            "col1": "3",
            "col2": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Col1 and Col2 were just incremental in the example. The format would be below:

Comment: {
   "structure": {
      "Id": "id",
      "Address": "address"
   },
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "address": "xyz"
      },
      {
         "id": "3",
         "address": "tgv"
      }
   ]
}

Comment: OK, I updated the answer.

Comment: worked like a charm. I did not want to hard code the cols. So first as you suggested using dataframe.to_dist and getting the columns dict and using it in the json.dumps